# Calculating Wilks' $\lambda$ to test LDA result

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis

I am using DFA to analyze my data in R.

In SPSS it gives Wilks' $\lambda$ with the output, but in R I couldn't determine how to compute it. I have found code that is available to calculate the Wilks' $\lambda$ value for MANOVA.

I am new to R and it would be helpful if anyone can help me to compute $\lambda$ value for the LDA in R.

Comment: The man's name is Wilks, not Wilk. Wilks' lambda is the proportion of within-groups sum of squares to total sum of squares. Take these SS from ANOVA table for discriminant scores.

Answer (score 2):

I found good information on the [Wikipedia page on Linear Discriminant Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) but the English page is not as clear as the [French one](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyse_discriminante_lin%C3%A9aire#S.C3.A9parabilit.C3.A9_-_Evaluation_globale) where they give the formula for both Wilks' lambda and Fisher's F.

Wilks' lambda is the ratio of the determinants from the within-group covariance matrix to the total covariance matrix $\cfrac{|W|}{|V|}$, $W$ (resp. $V$) being the restriction of the within-group (resp. global) covariance matrix to the *currently selected parameters*.